Getting TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE Error When Installing Certain npm Packages
I'm encountering an issue while installing some npm packages. Specifically, when I try to install packages like eslint, I get the following error:
npm error code TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE
npm error TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE: Unrecognized archive format

However, some other packages install successfully without any errors. I'm not sure what is causing this issue.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

Cleared the npm cache using npm cache clean --force.
Updated npm to the latest version.
Checked for internet connectivity issues.
Tried using multiple Node.js versions, including LTS versions.
Tested the installation on different Windows versions (Windows 11 24H2 and multiple versions of Windows 10).

Despite these steps, the problem persists.
Additional Info:

Node.js version: v22.11.0
npm version: 10.9.1
Operating system: Windows 11 24H2

I tried installing packages like **eslint **using npm install eslint. I expected the installation to complete successfully, just like other packages that I installed without issues. Instead, I received the error TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE: Unrecognized archive format.
A complete log link: https://pastebin.com/ZhJ15vXV

Try with a VPN or changing the internet connection (a few more details here)
https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/7893
An update it was an issue on npm registry https://status.npmjs.org/incidents/bxvmmvlqzfds

If you're encountering this problem too, try switching to another package manager like PNPM.
